# Leaflet webview: Javascript/HTML setView geolocation error

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview, leaflet

I am trying to display a remote HTML webpage in my Android Studio WebView. The webpage shows some 2D geographic points data of a location zoomed over user's location like this:

```
var map = L.map('map', {
    layers: [osmMap],
    zoom: 15,
    maxZoom: 18,
    minZoom: 13,
    zoomControl: false
  }).locate({setView: true, maxZoom: 18});
```

The above JavaScript helps zoom the map over user's location, which works fine in PC browser and mobile phone browser. But this doesn't work in the Android Studio WebView and the location is zoomed to wrong place (middle of nowhere).

Instead of above, if I zoom to a particular location like this, it works fine in Android WebView.

```
 var map = L.map('map', {
    layers: [osmMap],
    center: [my_lat, my_long],
    zoom: 15,
    maxZoom: 18,
    minZoom: 13,
    zoomControl: false
```

Researching and googling reveals that (see [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-permissions-in-cross-origin-iframes)) cross-origin permissions for iframes are deprecated. But I am using WebView and I am not sure if this issue is related to my problem.

Also, I already have the followings in my Android manifest.xml as suggested [here](https://developer.android.com/develop/sensors-and-location/location/permissions#java).

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
```

Does anyone have any idea how can I use Leaflet's locate with setView in my HTML page for Android's WebView or what tricks i am missing?

Answer (score 0):

this link help you to get current geolocation of user:
[get geolocation](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-get-current-gps-location-programmatically-on-android)

then send lat&long to webview and set the your lat &long to setview of map.